# How can I backprop over PyTorch LSTM built from primitive tensor operations (eg not `nn.LSTM`)

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

**EDIT** : the problem with my implementation was trying to extract my `output`, IE a one-hot vector, directly from the hidden state. I added a dense layer on top instead and it works fine.

---

I'm trying to make an LSTM from more primitive operations in PyTorch, and use `torch.autograd` features to backprop errors. I'd like it to be "online", in that `h` and `c` accumulate their state over time, and at each timestep there's 1 character in, and 1 out.

This is a character-level rnn, so:

- my vocablulary is 30 characters (lowercase a-z, and some punctuation)
- `inp` is a onehot vector of length 30.
- `h` and `c` are of length 30 + 100. The first 30 of `h` is my "output"
- my loss compares the `target` char, one-hot encoded, against those first 30 indices of `h`.
- I accumulate `loss` over 10 steps, and then don't know how to properly backprop it. The following is a (poor) attempt.

**TL;DR. How do I properly backprop for this LSTM?**

```
    def ff(inp, h, c):
        xh = torch.cat((inp, h), 0)
        f = (xh @ Wf + bf).sigmoid()
        i = (xh @ Wi + bi).sigmoid()
        g = (xh @ Wg + bg).tanh() # C-bar, in some literature
        c = f * c + i * g
        o = (xh @ Wo + bo).sigmoid()
        h = o * c.tanh()
        return h, c

    loss = torch.zeros(1)
    def bp(out, target, lr):
        global Wf, Wi, Wg, Wo
        global bf, bi, bg, bo
        global h, c
        global loss

        # Accumulate loss every step
        loss += (-target * out[:out_n].softmax(dim=0).log()).sum()

        # Every 10 chars, run backprop
        if i % 10 == 0:
            loss.backward()

            with torch.no_grad():
                for param in [Wf, Wi, Wg, Wo, bf, bi, bg, bo]:
                    param -= lr * param.grad
                    param.grad.zero_()

            h.detach_()
            c.detach_()
            loss.detach_()
            loss = torch.zeros(1)

        return loss
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with this implementation? Correctness of implementation aside, this should work with autograd just fine.

Comment: @Jatentaki The loss drops a little, not much, and bottoms out far from the point where samples make sense. I think I've implemented it improperly. I think the idea of using `h` like `output = h[:out_size]`, and using that for the `loss` is unique. Also the idea of 1-in, 1-out, and backproping over 10 steps is unique, so, I'm afraid I've been too unique.

Comment: Right, so I also believe you implemented it incorrectly, but it is not an issue with backprogation itself. It's just that the math is broken somewhere. I would suggest you rewrite the code in object-oriented fashion, avoiding using global variables (they are very error-prone). Since you're using global variables and pasting only part of the code, it's very hard to reason about it in its current state.